# What is the difference b/w onReceivedHttpError and onReceivedError for WebView Client

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, webviewclient

I am trying to understand the difference b/w https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html

onRecievedHttpError and onRecievedError.

For me I always get both of these callbacks for all errors in my webpage?
Why we have two callbacks then.

Answer (score 4):

[`onReceivedError()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceError))

> Report web resource loading error to the host application. These errors usually indicate inability to connect to the server.

It's about network/server errors. The errors are not HTTP errors but are 
unrecoverable resource errors (file not found, no network connection, server not found for the main resource, 
etc.). If there is a network error, there cannot be a HTTP error code transmitted.

[`onReceivedHttpError()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onReceivedHttpError(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest,%20android.webkit.WebResourceResponse))

> Notify the host application that an HTTP error has been received from the server while loading a resource. HTTP errors have status codes >= 400.